# Can't bind input variable using router-outlet - Angular

Tags: angular, observable, router-outlet

I'm aware this question has been asked before but I am pretty stumped here and new to Angular so could use an explanation.

I have my Prints component, List component, and details component. The print component subscribes to an observable to retrieve my backend data.

```
export class PrintsComponent implements OnInit {
public items: Item[];
  constructor(private printServ: BackendDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.printServ.getPrints().subscribe( 
      (printData: Item[]) => {
        this.items = printData;
 
    }), (error: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
      alert(error);
    }
  }
}
```

I then can pass this data via an input variable to my Print List component

```
In Prints.html
 <app-prints-list [listItems]="items"></app-prints-list>

export class PrintsListComponent implements OnChanges {
 @Input('listItems')items: Item[];  //+ constructor etc
```

But the problem then arises when trying to dynamically change my details display. I am subscribing to the Params Observable to retrieve the URL id for each item on the list, and then trying to display that in the details component. Below is a picture just to clarify my intent of the end result I want

[image]

This requires me to use a router outlet and so can't bind the retrieved data to my input variable

```
PrintList.component.html
<br>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 1px;">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <app-print-item *ngFor="let itemEl of items; let i = index" 
        [printItem]="itemEl"
        [index]="i" ></app-print-item> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet> *****Displaying details component here***
    </div>
</div>
```

PrintDetails.component.ts

```
  items: Item[]; ** Need to assign my data to this variable!
  item: Item;
  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.initialiseVariableDefaults();
      }
    )  
  }
```

Backend Service

```
export class BackendDataService {
  public apiServiceUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

  public getPrints(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(`${this.apiServiceUrl}/item/all`);
  }
```

How can I modify my service so that it can store the data returned and share between both of these components (DB returns an array object) I have tried using Subject/ReplaySubjects to assign the variable but cannot figure it out,  thanks for your help !

Comment: Behavior subject

Comment: Thanks @Dalorzo, I have added this functionality to the service class ` data = new `BehaviorSubject<Item[]>(null);

  setItems(items: Item[]) {
    this.data.next(items);
  } 
  public getItems(): {
    return this.data;
  } `  Am I on the right track here? This still won't allow me to assign the Object[] variable in my details component to the set value of the observable when I subscribe

Comment: "*This requires me to use a router outlet*" - Why do you need the router outlet?  It seems like you *could* just use your `<app-print-details [item]="item">` instead of `<router-outlet>`

Comment: I need to dynamically change the view + new url id each time I click a new item, so router outlet was my attempt so far.. maybe I am over complicating it I will have a look, thanks.